# Yet another case of TempData disappearing between controller actions

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

So this is yet another case of setting TempData in a controller method, using RedirectToAction and then the TempData is gone. But the odd thing is I have a case where it does work for some odd reason. Here are my controller methods:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult UploadXml(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    if (files != null)
    {
        var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(files.First().FileName).ToLower();
        string errors = string.Empty;

        switch (fileExtension)
        {
            case ".xml":
                var doc = XDocument.Load(files.First().InputStream);
                TextGetter.ImportXmlDocument(doc, out errors);
                break;
            case ".xlsx":
                TextGetter.ImportExcelDocument(files.First().InputStream, out errors);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(errors))
        {
            TempData["FileValidationErrors"] = errors;
        }
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult AddMissingLanguages(FormCollection formCollection)
{
    try
    {
        TempData["NrOfLanguageNodesAdded"] = TextGetter.AddMissingLanguagesToNodes();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Error(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, ex);
        Response.StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        return Json(TextGetter.GetText(Constant.ERROR, Constant.TEXT_GLOBAL) + ": " + ex.Message, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    TempData.Keep("NrOfLanguageNodesAdded");
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

And here is how I use them in my view:

```
@if (TempData.ContainsKey("FileValidationErrors") && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TempData["FileValidationErrors"].ToString()))
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                @TextGetter.GetText("XmlValidationFailedMessage", "setup/translation")Failed to validate the uploaded xml file with the following errors:<br />
                @TempData["FileValidationErrors"].ToString()
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
@if (TempData.ContainsKey("NrOfLanguageNodesAdded"))
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                Number of missing nodes added:<br />
                @TempData["NrOfLanguageNodesAdded"].ToString()
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

So here is the odd part, when I call the method "UploadXml", the TempData does persist when I redirect to the index and the message in it is shown in the view. But it does NOT work when I call "AddMissingLanguages", and I have tried numerous things like using ".keep" and ".peek" at various stages and what not, but no matter what I do it never works for the second controller action method.

Anyone have an idea of why this is the case?

Comment: What does `TextGetter.AddMissingLanguagesToNodes()` return?

Comment: @insane_developer it just returns an int.

Comment: What happens when you reverse the order of your `if` statements? How about if you just try to write out the `TempData` values on the page (not use them in `if` statements)?

Comment: @Jonathan I don't think it will help because the moment I hit the Index method the TempData is gone. I have checked and it is still available right before I call RedirectToAction. So it must be something I am doing in TextGetter.AddMissingLanguagesToNodes();

Comment: But one way to fix this is to not use tempdata in that method at all, and do something else. I could use a session variable but that lives for longer than I need, and another way is to use a parameter in the Index method, works also works, but just feels amateurish.

Comment: Those are 2 separate `POST` methods, and they each redirect to `Index`. `TempData` will only live until, and be available in the next request (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1#tempdata). Each of those `POST` methods are triggering separate requests. So I don't see how you could have both `TempData` values available in both. You could try `.Keep()` in your *view*, but depending on what else is going on in there, it may or may not work as expected.

Comment: @Jonathan After some testing, yes the second controller methods triggers a lot of work behind the scenes which clears the tempdata. I have tried different solutions for keeping temporary data but none works as intended in this specific case. I could just send the value as a parameter to Index, but that gets send as a GET and isn't a very good solution. Do you have any suggestions for other ways of transferring temp data from one view to another?

Comment: You could put those 2 properties into the view model for the page...